# SharePoint 2007: Items in Search Administration cannot open

Tags: search, central-administration, search-scope

The application I working on is developed on top of SharePoint 2007 environment, the issue I faced is in CA's Search Administration, all the items like Content Source, Scope and etc cannot click, when I clicked on the link, it hit the error below.

[image]

I've login with admin with sufficient rights to access the page, and I verify the files was in layout folder, wonder why it will hit page not found issue. No suspect log was captured in Event Viewer as well. There is also no major changes recently as well.

Please advise where should I start troubleshoot?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Is it something to do with SSP DB crashed or something?anyone? please help

Comment: Have you modified any files under _layouts? Like master pages or style sheets?

Comment: ya I did modified files under _layouts, but I'm sure its not the default SharePoint file

Answer (score 1):

Is recreating SSP an alternative? If yes, it would be quickest way to try to resolve this.

Also if you modified default SharePoint files under _layouts, revert them back and see if it helps. Sometimes modifying those pages break SharePoint in ways one cannot imagine.

Comment: ya it could be an alternative way, but somehow it is in the production environment, if recreate sure will impact the application

Comment: Please check the _layouts modifications to be sure.